# What wrong with my MVC default routing?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am running a basic MVC dot net core 2.0 set up,

My routing set up is:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
            );
```

If I go to [URL]/Controller

It Gives me a 404, but if enter [URL]/Controller/Action it works...

Shouldn't Index be added by default in this example?

Comment: Is that the only route you have? (what you have shown will work fine)

Comment: That was the only route, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Strange. Is just [URL]/ taking your to the `Index()` method of `HomeController` or is that also resulting in a 404?

Comment: `That was the only route` - Just so you are aware, Areas and Attribute Routing both add routes to the route table. Are you using either of these?

Comment: @NightOwl888 I'm not sure what they are, but I will be researching this later.